# typescript buggy behavior with enum

Tags: typescript, enums

Lets take a look at this example. First i create enum

```
enum myEnum {
  a = 'a', 
  b = 'b'
}
```

now i make similar enum but I add one more numeric ! ( this is important) value

```
enum myExtendedEnum {
    a = "a", 
    b = "b", 
    //this can be any number 
    c = 11, 
}
```

now look at this.

```
const returnsMyEnum = function() : myEnum {
    return 48;  
}

const returnMyExtendedEnum = function() : extendedEnum {
    return 48; 
}
```

Guess which one of above function are buggy for typescript? I would expect both but nope, only the `returnsMyEnum` one. Do you understand whats happen here or i should rather open bug report in typescript repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question. What you are using here is called [heterogeneous enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#heterogeneous-enums).

But the problem doesn't come from that. It comes from the fact that you are using `numeric` values.

This example will compile just fine:

```
enum NumericEnum {
  a = 23
}

const numeric = (): NumericEnum => 4;
```

Any `enum` that has a `numeric` value will widen the type to `numeric`. The reason for this is `bitwise operators`. People are used to use `numeric enums` assign power of 2 values and `bitwise` to signal multiple values. Something like this:

```
enum Flags {
 value1 = 1
 value2 = 2
 value3 = 4
 value4 = 8
}
```

Now you can use something like this `Flags.value1 | Flags.value4`. This value signals that you have both `value1` and `value4`. Because this is a common use `TS` decided to widen the type to `number`.

Comment: Well ineed this is heterogeneous enum. But it doesnt explain the source of fact one function is ok while another is not. Maybe i dont understand what you mean by `widen the type to numeric`. https://tsplay.dev/N9PO8w here we can see js output and i dont see anything special in the enum where one of the value is numeric.

Comment: It doesn't matter what code it gets generated. When using a numeric value, the type for the enum values is actually number and not your subset. That's why it's enough to have an enum with only one numeric value for the behaviour to be observable.

Comment: You might want to link to [the handbook section on enum compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#enums) (although it just says `enum`s are mutually compatible with `number`, which isn't true for `string`-only enums).  You could also point to various GitHub issues like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32690 to indicate that this is a known pain point for people

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the links. I'll try yo be more diligent in the future.